# Initial FIDE rating Question

Tags: tournament, rating, fide

According to FIDE, if I win half of my games in my first FIDE tournament, then my rating = the average of my opponents ratings.

If a tournament has 10 rounds, and I can only play the first 3 (and in this example let’s say I win 1.5 points), will my initial rating become the average of these 3 opponents or will this not count as a part of my full initial rating?

Looking through the handbook, I see no rule that says I can’t just leave a tournament after drawing the first round against a 2000 and my rating becoming 2000 (because the average of 1x2000 player/#of players = 2000.

Can anyone clarify from the rules exactly what determines an initial rating given one does not fully finish a tournament?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if a tournament has 10 rounds, and I can only play the first 3 (and in
> this example let’s say I win 1.5 points), will my initial rating
> become the average of these 3 opponents or will this not count as a
> part of my full initial rating?

No and no.

The [FIDE rating regulations](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022017) say

> 7.14 A rating for a player new to the list shall be published only if it meets the following criteria:
>
> 7.14a If based on results obtained under 6.3, **a minimum of 5 games**.
>
> 7.14b If based on results obtained under 6.4, a minimum of 5 games played against rated opponents.
>
> 7.14c The condition of a minimum of 5 games need not be met in one tournament. Results from other tournaments played within consecutive
> rating periods of not more than 26 months are pooled to obtain the
> initial rating.
>
> 7.14d The rating is at least 1000.
>
> 7.14e The rating is calculated using all his results as if they were played in one tournament (it is not published until he has played at
> least 5 games) by using all the rating data available.

So, if you only play 3 games you will not have a rating. However if you later play another tournament then the results of those 3 games will be carried forward.